# Smoothly scroll to the top to an invalid text field in jquery

Tags: jquery

How do I smoothly scroll to the top of an invalid text field and select 
it when a user presses a submit? I have tried most of the `.animate` but it still won't work. Can someone help me with this?

```
$('#create').on('submit', function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $("#create").offset().top
    }, 2000);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add focus on animate..

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#create").offset().top
}, 2000, function () {
    $('input:first').focus();
});
```